# How do I write filepaths correctly in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all the files in a directory.

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir("C:\test\\")
for files in glob.glob("*.*"):
    print(files)
```

But this returns nothing, even though there are files in `C:\test\`

So... what's going on, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python

Comment: `\t` is a tab character.  That's why nothing matches.  Forward slashes work fine on Windows (only a DOS box needs backward slashes).  Or you can try using raw strings instead (like `r"C:\test"`) - but raw strings cannot end with an odd number of backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `"C:\test\\"` the `\t` evaluates to a tab character. What you want is `"C:/test/"` or `r"C:\test"` - the difference is that the first version makes use of the fact that all windows apis and thus also python support forward slashes, too. The second one is a raw string where no escape sequences exist.

Comment: ...or `"C:\\test\\"`.